# Can't get widgets to line up properly in GTK3 and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, gtk3

I've written a GUI to set the sensitivity for the trackpoint on my Thinkpad. It's written in Python3 and GTK3, and the widgets for adjustments are laid out on a `Gtk.Grid`. I have the interactive widgets laid out beside their label in a `Gtk.Label` laid out on a separate column.

The layout for the labels and the other widgets won't align properly. I've looked through the docs for GTK and have thus so far not been able to get the labels to line up correctly.

```
from cProfile import label
import gi
import trackpoint

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
tp_values=trackpoint.retrieve_config_settings()

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__(title="Trackpoint Settings")
        self.Box1 = Gtk.VBox(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.Box1)
        self.Grid1 = Gtk.Grid()
        self.Grid1.set_column_homogeneous(True)
        self.Grid1.set_row_baseline_position(1, 1)
        self.Box1.pack_start(self.Grid1, True, True, 0)
        self.ButtonBox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.Box1.pack_start(self.ButtonBox, False, False, 0)
        print (self.Grid1.get_row_spacing())

        self.tp_values = trackpoint.retrieve_config_settings()
        
        self.Widgets = []
        for count, item in enumerate(trackpoint.tp_labels):
            WidgetHolder = Gtk.Label.new(item[0])
            WidgetHolder.set_vexpand(True)
            WidgetHolder.set_yalign(0.5)
            print (WidgetHolder.get_yalign())
            print (WidgetHolder.get_vexpand())
            self.Widgets.append(WidgetHolder)
            if (item[1] == trackpoint.scale):
                WidgetHolder = Gtk.Scale.new_with_range(0,0,item[2],1)
                WidgetHolder.set_round_digits(1)
                WidgetHolder.set_value(float(tp_values[count]))
            if (item[1] == trackpoint.checkbutton):
                WidgetHolder = Gtk.CheckButton.new()
            self.Widgets.append(WidgetHolder)

            y_more = 0
            x_more = 0
        for count, item in enumerate(self.Widgets):
            if (count >= 12):
               y_more = 2 
               x_more = 12
            if (count % 2 == 0):
                self.Grid1.attach(item, 1+y_more, count-x_more, 1, 1) 
            if (count % 2 != 0):
                self.Grid1.attach(item, 2+y_more, count-x_more, 1, 1) 

        self.DefaultButton = Gtk.Button(label="Default")
        self.ButtonBox.pack_start(self.DefaultButton, False, False, 0)

        self.AdvancedButton = Gtk.Button(label="Advanced >>")
        self.AdvancedButton.connect("clicked", self.on_advanced_clicked)
        self.ButtonBox.pack_start(self.AdvancedButton, False, False, 0)

        self.ResetButton = Gtk.Button(label="Reset")
        self.ButtonBox.pack_end(self.ResetButton, False, False, 0)

        self.ApplyButton = Gtk.Button(label="Apply")
        self.ApplyButton.connect("clicked", self.on_apply_clicked)
        self.ButtonBox.pack_end(self.ApplyButton, False, False, 0)
        
    def on_advanced_clicked(self,widget):
        if (widget.get_label() != "Advanced <<"):
            widget.set_label("Advanced <<")
            for i in range(6, 25):
                win.show_all()
            self.resize(700,250)
        else:
            widget.set_label("Advanced >>")
            for i in range(6, 25):
                self.Widgets[i].hide()
            self.resize(400,100)

    def on_apply_clicked(self,widget):
        for count, item in enumerate(trackpoint.tp_labels):
            print (self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_name())
            if (self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_name() == "GtkScale"):
                print (self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_value())
                trackpoint.set_setting(trackpoint.tp_path + trackpoint.tp_labels[count] [0],\
                     str(int(self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_value())))
                trackpoint.store_changed_settings(trackpoint.tp_labels[count] [0],\
                     str(int(self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_value())))
            if (self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_name() == "GtkCheckButton"):
                trackpoint.set_setting(trackpoint.tp_path + trackpoint.tp_labels[count] [0],\
                     str(int(self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_value())))
                trackpoint.store_changed_settings(trackpoint.tp_labels[count] [0],\
                     ((str(int(self.Widgets[count*2+1].get_active())))))
    
    def on_scale_draw(self,widget,something):
            widget.set_value(200)

    def initial_show(self):
        win.show_all()
        for count, item in enumerate (self.Widgets):
            if (count > 5):
                self.Widgets[count].hide()
        self.resize(200,50)

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.initial_show()
Gtk.main()
```

[And here's the result.][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVF6k.png

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

nvm fixed it:

```
            y_more = 0
            x_more = 0
        for count, item in enumerate(self.Widgets):
            if (count >= 12):
               y_more = 2 
               x_more = 12
            if (count % 2 == 0):
                self.Grid1.attach(item, 1+y_more, count-x_more, 1, 1) 
            if (count % 2 != 0):
                self.Grid1.attach(item, 2+y_more, count-x_more-1, 1, 1)
```